# Очередность вывода потоков Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Приветсвую, как можно реализовать очередь потоков, чтоб они не играли в перегонки кто первый возьмет монитор, а шли строга по очереди по мере прогрева?

```
public class Airport {
    private final BlockingQueue<Band> bands;

Airport(int bandCount) {
    this.bands = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(bandCount, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < bandCount; i++) {
        bands.add(new Band("Полоса " + i));
    }
}

@NotNull
public Band waitForAvailableBand() throws InterruptedException {
    Band result = bands.take();
    System.out.println("Полоса " + result.name + " зарезервированна ");
    return result;
}

public void releaseBand(@NotNull Band band) {
    bands.add(band);
}

static class Band  {
    public final String name;
    Band(String name) {this.name = name;}

}
}
public abstract class Plane extends Thread {
public final String name;
private final Airport airport;
private final int delay;

Plane(String name, Airport airport, int delay) {
    this.name = name;
    this.delay = delay;
    this.airport = airport;
}

public int getDelay() {
    return delay;
}

public static int rnd(int min, int max) {
    max -=min;
    return (int) (Math.random() * ++ max) + min;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int time = 1000;
    int time2 = 10000;
    int timeEver = rnd(time,time2);
    Airport.Band band;
    try {
        System.out.println("Прогрев начался: " + name);
        Thread.sleep(timeEver);
        System.out.println("Прогрев завершился: " + name + " " + timeEver);
        System.out.println("Резервируем полосу для: " + name);

        band = airport.waitForAvailableBand();

        try {
            System.out.println("Взлетаем: " + name + " c полосы " + band.name);
            Thread.sleep(getDelay());
            System.out.println("Взлетел: " + name);
                } finally {
                    airport.releaseBand(band);
                }

    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    Airport airport = new Airport(2);

    ArrayList<Plane> planes = new ArrayList<>();

    planes.add(new Passenger("1", airport, 5000));
    planes.add(new Cargo("2", airport, 10000));
    planes.add(new Passenger("3", airport, 5000));
    planes.add(new Passenger("4", airport, 5000));
    planes.add(new Cargo("5", airport, 10000));

        planes.forEach(plane -> {
            try {
               plane.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {}
        });
        System.out.println("Программа завершила свою работу");
    }
}
```

Далее идет вывод:

```
Прогрев начался: 2
Прогрев начался: 1
Прогрев начался: 4
Прогрев начался: 3
Прогрев начался: 5
Прогрев завершился: 1 1763
Резервируем полосу для: 1
Полоса Полоса 0 зарезервированна 
Взлетаем: 1 c полосы Полоса 0
Прогрев завершился: 4 2966
Резервируем полосу для: 4
Полоса Полоса 1 зарезервированна 
Взлетаем: 4 c полосы Полоса 1
Прогрев завершился: 3 3621
Резервируем полосу для: 3
Прогрев завершился: 5 4445
Резервируем полосу для: 5
Прогрев завершился: 2 6217
Резервируем полосу для: 2
Взлетел: 1
Полоса Полоса 0 зарезервированна 
Взлетаем: 3 c полосы Полоса 0
Взлетел: 4
Полоса Полоса 1 зарезервированна 
Взлетаем: 5 c полосы Полоса 1
Взлетел: 3
Полоса Полоса 0 зарезервированна 
Взлетаем: 2 c полосы Полоса 0
Взлетел: 5
Взлетел: 2
Программа завершила свою работу
```

В моменте где прогрев завершился: Пассажирский1 и Пассажирский2, взлет происходит Пассажирский1 и грузовой3

Comment: При такой постановке задачи потоки не нужны, поскольку они не дадут строгой очередности. Здесь будет достаточно Queue

Comment: @kami в дальнейшем, я хочу попытаться реализовать, что полоса неактивна какое-то время, но самолеты начали прогрев и как только полоса открылась, они встали в очередь в том порядке в котором прогрелись, как тут без потоков?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать честную очередь на локе

```
 static class Band  {
        public final String name;
        private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true); // <-- FAIR LOCK

        Band(String name) {this.name = name;}

        private boolean tryLock() {return lock.tryLock();}

        private void unlock() {lock.unlock();}

    }
```

Но я присоединяюсь к совету @kami - сделай лучше очередь событий. См. `PriorityQueue`

---

### Простой пример с очередью полос

Это проще, чем очередь событий. Но в целом, если делать сложную логику, то лучше делать очередь событий.

```
public class Airport {
    private final BlockingDeque<Band> bands;

    Airport(int bandCount) {
        this.bands =  new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(bandCount, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < bandCount; i++) {
            bands.add(new Band("Полоса " + i));
        }
    }

    @NotNull // !!!
    public Band waitForAvailableBand() {
        Band result = bands.take(); // Будет ждать, пока полоса на освободится, поэтому внешний цикл и Thread.sleep больше не нужен
        System.out.println("Полоса " + result.name + " зарезервированна ");
        return result;
    }

    public void releaseBand(@NotNull Band band) {
        bands.add(band);
    }

static class Band  {
        public final String name;
        // отдельный лок на полосу больше не нужен
        // private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        Band(String name) {this.name = name;}


    }
 ....
```

Comment: протестил, оно не работает) они как взлетали в рандомном порядке, так и взлетают)

Comment: Это из-за `Thread.sleep(1000)`. Переделай на очереди.

Comment: я вот бьюсь с этими очередями какой день и не понимаю, куда их вставлять, я сделал очередь в main, и добавил в эту очередь все объекты, а что дальше делать не пойму

Comment: Например, в аэропорту замени список полос на блокирующую очередь полос (`new ArrayBlockingQueue(bandCount, true`). Соответственно, `tryLockedBand` больше не будет итерироваться по списку, а будет просто забирать полосу из очереди, а если очередь пустая, то блокироваться и ждать (`queue.take`). Когда самолёт взлетел, он будет класть полосу обратно в очередь.

Comment: И, кстати, д.б. не `band`, а `runway` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runway

Comment: У тебя в коде выше написанно BlockingDeque, должно же быть BlockingQeque, как я понял, функции tryLockedBand больше нет, я отредактировал код в топике, еще отредактировал функцию рандомной генерации времени на прогрев, т.к она генерировала одинаковое значение для всех, из main перетащил в метод run, вывод вроде похож на правду, буду тестить) А если допустим сделать, что при старте программы, все полосы неактивны какое-то время, а самолеты греются, это какими инструментами реализовать?

Comment: ну глянь уже JavaDoc  - `BlockingQueue` это интерфейс, `ArrayBlockingQueue` - имплементация, которая позволяет "честные" очереди.

Comment: Пока самолёты греются, они и не требуют полосу. Если полосы неактивны в начале, тогда создавай аэропорт без полос и добавляй их с задержкой из другого потока.

Comment: Я к тому ,что ты опечатался в коде) Где ты приводишь простой пример с очередью полос.

Answer (score 1):

ЛИБО) можете использовать синхронизаторы из пакета concurrent

Answer (score 0):

Используй после theard.start

```
  Theard.join()
```

Пока не выполнится, следующий не запустится

Comment: Я использую join 
planes.forEach(plane -> {
plane.join
}